# How to upload image file to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to upload an image to the firebase storage so i can progress on my project, but when i run the following code, the image stored looks like this:
[image]

I read the documentation and it says it have to be a File or Blob, so i came here to ask, any help is appreciated

This is the upload code:

```
const RegisterProperty = () => {

    const cameraImage = require('../pics/camera.png')
    const baseImage = require('../pics/baseImage.jpg')
    const imagemTeste = 'https://i.postimg.cc/mrfdKk2M/smoking.png'

    const uploadImagem = async () => {
        // const imageBlob = new Blob([baseImage],"filename.jpg",{type: 'image/jpeg'})
        // const response = await fetch(imagemTeste)
        // const imageBlob = await response.blob()

        uploadBytes(storageRef, baseImage, metadata).then(() => {
            console.log('Uploaded')
        })
        console.log(typeof(imagemTeste2))
    }
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: You were on the right track with converting the filedata to a blob first. Then you upload the blob. See the answer I posted for the code we use to convert to blob.

Comment: The error screenshot is, I believe, unrelated to your issue. I see those often lately, but never so far with any ill effects.

Answer (score 1):

Take the local path use it like below.

Note that there is a newer syntax for blobs, but we're not using it yet so I can only share this:

```js
function urlToBlob(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('error', reject);
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      }
    });
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob'; // convert type
    xhr.send();
  });
}


const blob = await urlToBlob(localPath);

uploadBytes(storageRef, blob, metadata).then(() => {
  console.log('Uploaded')
})
```

Comment: It still returns the same thing in the firebase, i did it like in your example

Comment: In the local path, should i write it like this? const blobTeste = await urlToBlob('../pics/baseImage.jpg')

Comment: I am also getting an error in the react native, see the edited question

Comment: I believe you need to pass `urlToBlob` the absolute file path, not a relative one. In our case we get the absolute portion of the path using `documentDirectory` from `'expo-file-system'`. I believe it should start with `file://`

Comment: Tried the following paths const blobTeste = await urlToBlob("file:///D:/Arquivos/TCC/client/pics/baseImage.jpg") and const absolutePath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'download.jpeg', both didn't work

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue might be, unfortunately. When you read the fileData using Expo's FileSystem module, it returns a string, right? It could be an issue with the encoding of the file, but I'm just guessing now.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help! I'd try testing with a plaintext file without any extension or metadata to reduce complexity as much as possible until you find a way that works.

Answer (score 0):

work for me try this one in picimage fuction

```
 const pickImage = async () => {
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
  allowsEditing: true,
  aspect: [1, 1],
  quality: 1,
});

if (!result.canceled) {
  console.log("this is image link",result.assets[0].uri)
  setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
  const url = result.assets[0].uri
  
  
  function urlToBlob(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.addEventListener('error', reject);
      xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          resolve(xhr.response);
        }
      });
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.responseType = 'blob'; // convert type
      xhr.send();
    });
  }
  const blob = await urlToBlob(url);
   setBlobImage(blob)
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).